# Slash character in file path creating exception in javafx media

Tags: java, audio, javafx

I found many similar questions on this topic in this forum, but none of the solutions of those questions working for me and this problem is really making me frustrated.

I have the following method which should play a **wav** file when I call it.
Directory of the wav file is: **ProjectFolder/src/resources/Sounds/click.wav**

```
public static void Click()
{          
    String clickSound = "/resources/Sounds/click.wav";
    Media hit = new Media(new File(clickSound).toPath().toString());
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(hit);
    mediaPlayer.play();
}
```

But it results in the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 0: \resources\Sounds\click.wav
    at javafx.scene.media.Media.<init>(Media.java:385)
```

When I set the value of the string **clickSound** "resources/Sounds/click.wav" instead of "/resources/Sounds/click.wav", the exception says illegal character in path at index 9.

So I am guessing that it is considering '/' character as an illegal character. I tried using '\' instead of '/', but the result was same.

I do not want to change the location of the **wav** file for certain reason. How can access I access that **wav** file from **ProjectFolder/src/resources/Sounds/click.wav** and play it without any exception?

Any kind of help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it work if you supply the full path?  Do you know the folder it's running from?

Comment: I tried using the full path of the wav file, it resulted in the same illegal character exception. @phflack

Comment: It does not matter, if you use `\ ` or `/` since your OS seems to use `\ ` as path separator and therefore replaces any `/`s in the path resulting in an invalid URI...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/media/Media.html#Media-java.lang.String-):

> The source must represent a valid URI and is immutable. Only HTTP, HTTPS, FILE, and JAR URLs are supported. If the provided URL is invalid then an exception will be thrown.

You are passing in the path to a file, instead of a URI.

You almost certainly don't want a file here anyway; for example, when you deploy your application it will typically be deployed as a jar file, and the media will be an entry in that jar file (so it won't be a file in its own right at all). On top of that, the `resources` folder is typically part of the source code structure, and for obvious reasons the source code is not usually available at runtime.

Assuming your resources are being deployed to the root of the classpath, which is the usual setup, you need something like

```
String clickSound = "/Sounds/click.wav";

Media hit = new Media(getClass().getResource(clickSound).toExternalForm());
```

Comment: The problem is, I can not reference getClass() method from a static context and I must call Click() method from a static context or keep the Click() method static.  @James_D

Comment: @user8544110 So just do `MyClass.class.getResource(...)` instead of `getClass().getResource(...)`, where `MyClass` is the name of the current class. (It is almost certainly a bad design to make that method static, though, since it looks like it should be in a controller, in some loose sense.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and suggestion. It worked at last. @James_D

Answer (score 0):

You listed the file as in directory "ProjectFolder/src/resource/Sounds/click.wav" but when trying to access you have "resources" instead of "resource"

Comment: It was a typing mistake. Thanks for your response.